# Pull the data from an api and store in mongo

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, api, express

I wanted to pull JSON data from a fetching external API(weather API) and store the JSON data into Mongo DB for further use.

```
const url = `my url`
const options = {
    "method" : "GET",   
}
const result = await fetch(url,options)
    .then(res =>res.json())
    .catch(e => {
        console.log("ERROR: ", e)
    })

console.log("RESPONSE:" , result)
res.status(200).json(result)
//  res.status(200).send(response.url)
const db = new db ({result})
newJobs.save(result);
console.log('save to db')
console.log(db)
```

`op: { _id: 60dd0299ee1ee32224dfc88d }`

I want to store data coming from that API into mongo

this is the code snippet.
I'm successfully getting the data and an id has been creating in mongo but I'm not able to store the result JSON data into mongo

Comment: Here is a great tutorial to get started with mongo on node.js: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp